# Time-specific panel regression output in R

Tags: r, panel-data

I am using R and I have a panel dataset of firm-level financial information over a 4 year time period. The panel is unbalanced and the total number of observations is 73 (roughly 20 per time interval). The model analyzes the effect that changes in factor input prices has on firm revenue.

```
> fit <-plm(log(Y)~log(PK)+log(PL)+log(PPK)+log(TA)+log(CON)+log(CON2), data=pdata, index=c("BANK","T"), model="random")
```

The first three independent variable coefficients, when summed, are a metric for competition in the industry. 
What I am trying to do see the regression output at each time period, allowing me to see the changes in the competition measure over time.
Is there a command or function that I can use to see the regression output at each time interval?

I have tried running simple `lm` regressions for each time period, but the `CON` and `CON2` variable cause a singularity error because they are constant across all firms at each time period.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into models that allow for time-varying coefficients, e. g. state-space models/dynamic linear models.